# MYSQL only returns the last row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all the `$title` from a mysql table called `pages`.

But I do not understand why I can only get the last one using my code bellow:

```
    if( ! $stmt = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT id, title FROM pages") ) {
  die( $db_conx->error );
}

$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
  die( $stmt->error );
}
$stmt->bind_result($id, $title);
$stmt->store_result();

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $value[] = array('id'=>$id, 'title'=>$title);
}

echo $title;
```

is there anything missing from my code?

I'm absolutely baffled with this. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `var_dump($value);` instead of `echo $title;`

Comment: @YourCommonSense, i just love your very sarcastic and unhelpful comments that you leave every now and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to echo out the variable `$title` but you are in fact appending the results of your query to `$value`.

If you replace

```
echo $title;
```

with

```
print_r($value);
```

I am pretty sure that you will get the information you are looking for.

Your code appends elements to an array. Print_r is a quick nasty way of checking what is in an array (or other) but you will probably want to use a control structure like a foreach to get through the results in a meaningful manner:

```
foreach($value as $val)
{
    echo "ID: ".$val[0]." - Title: ".$val[1]."<br>\r\n";
}
```